# CloudDeploy, FormPage: showing first option

Tags: wolfram-cloud

In this example I use a simple code like:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4}

CloudDeploy[
 FormPage["N" -> {1, 2, 3, 4},
  ListPlot[{data, data*#N}, Joined -> {True, False}] &]]
```

When I go to this `CloudObject` I see:

[image]

After pushing the "Submit"-button, I will see the result.

My question is: Before I submit, I would like to see the first option when I open the `CloudObject` like:

[image]

Anyone a suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to use `"Input"` attribute of a form field:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
CloudDeploy[
  FormPage[
    "N" -> <|
      "Interpreter" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
    , "Input" -> 3
    |>
  , ListPlot[{data, data*#N}, Joined -> {True, False}] &
  ]
, Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

[image]